# ubuntu + router + usb wifi

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to set up a cluster.

The physical elements are :

```
internet access : netgear wifi
host A : ubuntu + RJ 45 + usb wifi
host b : ubuntu + RJ 45
router : dlink (rj45 + wifi)
host c : mac book air
```

The logical networks are :

- internet : 10.0.0.0/24
- LAN : 192.168.0.0/24

host A is connected to internet thanks to its usb wifi card connecting to netgear. It is also connected to the LAN thanks to its eth0.

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:5a:69:33:d6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:05:0f:36:30:ba  
          inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

My macbook is connected to the network by wifi (using the dlink wifi interface). I am trying to get internet acces in chrome through a gateway opened on host A.

```
MacBook-Air-$ netstat -nr
```

Routing tables

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGSc            4        0     en0
10                 192.168.0.100      UGSc            0        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             35    10672     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.0          link#4             UCS             3        0     en0
192.168.0.1        54:b8:a:a:40:20    UHLWIir         6      342     en0   1164
192.168.0.100      0:21:5a:69:33:d6   UHLWIir         1      462     en0   1093
192.168.0.101      127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     link#1                          UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::60c:ceff:fee1:b448%en0            4:c:ce:e1:b4:48                 UHLWIi          en0
fe80::3e15:c2ff:febe:5906%en0           3c:15:c2:be:59:6                UHLWIi          en0
fe80::8638:35ff:fe4f:7936%en0           84:38:35:4f:79:36               UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           fe80::1%lo0                     UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%lo0/32                           fe80::1%lo0                     UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0

MacBook-Air:~ romain$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 84:38:35:4f:79:36 
    inet6 fe80::8638:35ff:fe4f:7936%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 06:38:35:4f:79:36 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
```

And I am lost here : I can't have acces to have access to internet through chrome (or even to ping something) (unfortunately I don't have the error on my trace, sorry). I am quite new at setting networks, and I suspect there is something wrong on the way gateways are opened ?

Comment: Can you provide the model number of your Netgear and D-Link devices? It doesn't make sense to me why you would try to access the internet through the Ubuntu host. Can you not just have internet from the Netgear to the Dlink and let the Dlink route traffic to everything else? Or just connect the computers directly to the Netgear?